# How to correctly send an http request from angular to python

Tags: angularjs, django, post, request

I'm using AngularJS for the front-end and Django for the backend of a web app I'm working on. Right now I'm working on sharing files and I'm having a strange problem. I have a Controller like:

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('FileManagerApp').controller('postController', ['$scope', '$http',
function($scope, $http){
    $scope.edit = function(){

    var postdata = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/share',
        data: {
           to: $scope.to
        },
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFTOKEN': "{{ csrf_token }}"
        }
    };
    $http(postdata)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.to = data;
        })
    }
}]);
})(angular);
```

This is my view where I want to show the response: BUT I GOT NOTHING

```
def share(request):

     print("sharing to ....")
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        email = data['to']          
        response_data = {}
        response_data = str(email).split(" ")[0]
        response_data["success"] = True

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),    content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using request.body to get the full raw request body, you can use request.post to get a dictionary of post data.

See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/

```
email = request.POST.get('to', None)
```